# GWT: Sharing information between instances of the same module

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I've read extensively about this, and I am wondering if there is a better way.

My requirement is essentially the same as [this OPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325160/displaying-a-widget-in-a-new-window-in-gwt).
I need to display a complex table in a new browser tab. I followed the responders advice, and loaded a new instance of the main module into the new tab. I did so like [this blog post](http://gwtinnewbrowser.blogspot.ca/2010/10/gwt-widget-in-new-browser.html#comment-form) suggests. I can't simply use a dialogBox like so many people have suggested in similar questions.

I did all this without really thinking about the consequences. In particular, I now need to send a lot of information back and forth between the two instances. From what I've read, exporting to JSNI methods, or using GWT exporter are ways to do this. I've already spent soo long just getting it to be able to load certain views based on a javascript variable set when opening a new tab.

Is this a common way of addressing this problem? It seems like opening a widget in a new browser tab would be a relatively common requirement, yet the solution is getting more and more complex and cumbersome the farther I go. Is that just how it is?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Setting a cookie in one tab affects cookies in all tabs of the same domain immediately, i.e. without reloading any of those tabs. (Just tested it in current versions of Chrome, FF and IE.)

Couldn't that be of some use?

Answer (score 0):

I would give HTML 5 Messaging a try. This allows you to send JSON data between two windows. with JSNI, it should not be a big deal.

http://bear-z.com/gwt/implementing-postmessage-technology-into-gwt/

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/messaging.html